# Тройная вложенность

Tags: mysql

Есть 3 таблицы: с рейсами самолетов `flight`, с названиями аэропортов `airport` и с названиями городов `city`. Нужно взять один из рейсов и узнать город вылета и город прилет.

в таблице `flight` аэропорты обозначены `fromAirport` и `toAirport` эти коды соответствуют `airport.code`. У каждого `airport.code` есть свой `airport.cityCode`. Далее по этому `cityCode` нужно выбрать город `city.code`. У каждого `city.code` есть свой `city.name` его то мне и нужно взять. Такая вот тройная вложенность.

Подскажите как это сделать одним запросом?

**UPD**

Пробовал использовать вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM flights, airport, city
  WHERE flights.fromAirport = airport.code AND flights.toAirport = airport.code
  ORDER BY flights.upload DESC
  LIMIT 1;
```

Как сюда третью таблицу впихать - понятия не имею.

Comment: Что вы уже пробовали сделать? Что именно не получается?

Comment: Сделать это можно использовав связывание через JOIN нужных таблиц.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, SELECT * 
FROM  `flights` ,  `airport` , `city`
WHERE   `flights`.`fromAirport` =  `airport`.`code` 
and  `flights`.`toAirport` =  `airport`.`code`
ORDER BY  `flights`.`upload` DESC 
LIMIT 1 у меня даже с двойной не получилось, как сюда третью таблицу впихать понятия не имею

Comment: Вам нужно по 2 копии таблиц аэропортов и городов - отдельно для вылета и отдельно для прилёта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT f.flightNumber, cF.name townFrom, cT.name townTo
FROM flight f, airport aF, airport aT, city cF, city cT
WHERE f.fromAirport = aF.code 
  AND aF.cityCode = cF.code
  AND f.toAirport = aT.code 
  AND aT.cityCode = cT.code
-- AND f.flightNumber IN (123,456,789)
```

Comment: Похоже на то что мне нужно, на почему то ответом на ваш запрос получаю предупреждение `#1104 - The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay`. сам запрос немного подредактировал `SELECT * 
FROM flights f, airport aF, airport aT, city cF, city cT
WHERE f.fromAirport = aF.code
  AND aF.cityCode = cF.code
  AND f.toAirport = aT.code 
  AND aT.cityCode = cT.code`

Comment: Ну Вам просто говорят, что уж больно дохрена вариантов будет. Добавьте фильтр для получения данных только по нужным рейсам.

Comment: откуда же им там дохренам быть? ) там всего с пяток записей в таблице с рейсами `flights`. Попробовав разные фильтры, результ тот же

Comment: А городов и аэропортов - сколько? Ну и уж заодно - чему равно MAX_JOIN_SIZE в сессии...

Comment: вообщем разобрался, все хорошо

Comment: для озадаченных такой же проблемой - нужно верно расставить индексы, и все заработает

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с использованием конструкции `JOIN`:

```
SELECT f.code, cf.name AS fromCity, ct.name AS toCity FROM flight f
    INNER JOIN airport afrom ON f.fromAirport = afrom.code
    INNER JOIN airport ato ON f.toAirport = ato.code
    INNER JOIN city cf ON afrom.cityCode = cf.code
    INNER JOIN city ct ON ato.cityCode = ct.code
ORDER BY f.code;
```

А вот и [рабочий пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84499/5/0) на SQLFiddle.

Answer (score -1):

У вас должно быть примерно так:

```
SELECT name  FROM city 
JOIN airport ON city.code=airport.cityCode
JOIN flights ON airport.code=flights.fromAirport
WHERE flights.fromAirport=12345
```